# How would you implement a O(C^n) time complexity function using for loops?

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm

The only thing I can think of uses Math.pow() to calculate n before the loop and seems like a cop out.
C=2 in this example:

```
var oCN = function (n)
{
    var j = Math.pow(2, n);
    for (var i = 0; i <= j; i++) {
          console.log('cactus');  
    };
    return;
}
```

Comment: `Math.pow(2, n);` --- what this statement is about? It calculates the `2^n` and then *what*?

Comment: whoops, thanks for pointing that out.  It is meant to be n = Math.pow(2,n)

Comment: It's a good practice to not override the values of the arguments. So put it into the different variable then our function will do some job in an exponential fashion (as you want).

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU ? :-)

Comment: Ok thanks, so my question is, is there a way to implement a function with the same complexity with out just straight up calculating how many iterations you are going to want?

Comment: Yea, I watched the whole thing when you posted in on my last question

Comment: The "complexity" in your case is the number of "operations". Which means you need to run some "operation" `2^n` times. I don't know a better way to run something `N` times other than a good old `for`

Comment: If you need something that looks like "real" - implement a bubble sort. It's `O(N^2)`

Comment: And to pick some "real world" implementation with a given complexity - pick something from http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: So, if you consider an n^2 function, The way I would normally think about that is a for loop within a for loop rather than just calculating n^2 and then writing one for loop to iterate n^2 amount of times.  That being said I'm trying to look at a C^n function with a similar approach

Comment: That link looks very helpful, thanks

Comment: "The way I would normally think about that is a for loop within a for loop rather than just calculating n^2 and then writing one for loop to iterate n^2 amount of times." --- it does not matter. What matters is that the "computation cost" increases as a quadratic function. And internally it might be a single loop, nested loops or 50 loops.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and definitely clarifies my understanding.  Thanks again.

Comment: Are you trying to understand what kinds of real world algorithms would result in exponential complexity?

Comment: The naive recursive implementation of the Fibonacci number has about  `pow(2,n)` function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive algorithm like this one would grow exponentially with respect to `n`:

```
var oCN = function (C, n)
{
    if (n < 1) { console.log('cactus'); return; }
    for (var i = 0; i < C; i++) {
        oCN(C, n-1);
    }
}
```

The number of logged cacti is in the case of this algorithm is exactly `C^n`, which is of course `O(C^n)`. Eg. `oCN(2, 4)` logs `cactus` 16 times, `oCN(2, 5)` logs it 32 times, etc.

You won't typically see a lot of day-to-day algorithms that work in exponential time. If something *is* being done in exponential time there is a good chance the input size or constants are such that the big-O complexity doesn't matter very much at all (or at least, the implementer doesn't care very much), and so you probably won't be sitting around analyzing the complexity. Most normal stuff programmers want to do can either be done with a polynomial time algorithm right off the bat or with some fudging and sacrificing.